# Select element in CellList using SelectionModel or ListDataProvider

Tags: gwt, selectionmodel

I have used CellList for listing my data using ListDataProvider for managing the data and SelectionModel for selecting an element from CellList and generating events accordingly.

Now when i update or delete element using cellList.getList().set(index, bean) or cellList.getList().remove() it sucessfully do the operation. But after that it automatically selects the first record in CellList which i do not want.

Can anyone suggest how can i deselect the selected record in CellList?

Below is the code how i am initializing the selectionmodel and listprovider:

```
ListDataProvider<AppsBean> dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<AppsBean>();
CellList<AppsBean> appsCellList;
SingleSelectionModel<AppsBean>  singleSelectionModel;

ProvidesKey<AppsBean> keyProvider = new ProvidesKey<AppsBean>() {
        public Object getKey(AppsBean item) {
            // Always do a null check.
            return (item == null) ? null : item.getId();
        }
    };
    //here cell is the AbstractCell<AppsBean>    
    appsCellList = new CellList<AppsBean> (cell, keyProvider);
    dataProvider.addDataDisplay(appsCellList);
    appsCellList.setKeyboardSelectionPolicy(KeyboardSelectionPolicy.BOUND_TO_SELECTION);

    singleSelectionModel = new SingleSelectionModel<AppsBean>(keyProvider);
    appsCellList.setSelectionModel(singleSelectionModel);
    singleSelectionModel.addSelectionChangeHandler(new SelectionChangeEvent.Handler() {

        @Override
        public void onSelectionChange(SelectionChangeEvent event) {
            AppsBean selectedApp = singleSelectionModel.getSelectedObject();
            if (selectedApp != null)
                appsForm.fillApps(selectedApp);
        }
    });
```

When i am adding the new record:

```
dataProvider.getList().add(0, appsBean);
```

For updating the record:

```
AppsBean bean = singleSelectionModel.getSelectedObject();
dataProvider.getList().set(dataProvider.getList().indexOf(bean), appsBean);
```

And for delete:

```
int selectedIndex = dataProvider.getList().indexOf(singleSelectionModel.getSelectedObject());
dataProvider.getList().remove(selectedIndex);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to implement a KeyProvider in order to make sure that your selected DTO stays the same even when the object itself changes.
If you don't provide a KeyProvider it will probably use equals to compare the objects and if they change then you might run into problems.

```
ProvidesKey keyProvider = new ProvidesKey() {
    public Object getKey(Contact item) {
       //return the unique identifier for your DTO
       return (item == null) ? null : item.id;
    }
};
```

Then you have to initialize the CellTable and selectionModel with this keyProvider

```
 CellList cellList = new CellList(new ContactCell(),keyProvider);

 SelectionModel selectionModel = new SingleSelectionModel(keyProvider);
 cellList.setSelectionModel(selectionModel);
```

**Update**
De-selecting a selected object works like this:

```
 Object obj  = selectionModel.getSelectedObject();
 if (obj != null) {
     selectionModel.setSelected(obj,false);
 }
```

Comment: Its working for cellList.getList().set(index, bean). Thanks. But when i do cellList.getList().remove(index) it automatically select the first record in the list.  How can i deselect the current selection using code?

Comment: `Object obj  = selectionModel.getSelectedObject();
 if (obj != null) {
     selectionModel.setSelected(obj,false);
 }`

is working fine with one issue. The object is getting deselect perfectly. But when i try to select it again without selecting any other object then i am not able to select it. How can i do it?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Are you selecting the CellList entry programmatically or by clicking on it? What happens exactly? Does it work if you select another entry?

Comment: For example, i have 3 objects in list. I selected the 2nd entry and then programmatically calling deselect it as the above code provided by you. Thats working fine. Now manually i click on 2nd entry itself but no selection event being fired and nothing get happened. Then if i select first entry its working fine. And now again selecting the 2nd entry then also its working fine.

Comment: hmm that sounds like a bug to me. Which GWT version are you using and did you add a SelectionChangeHandler?

Comment: I am using GWT 2.3.0. And yes i do add SelectionChangeHandler on SelectionModel.

Comment: Hmm shouldn't happen. I will try to reproduce it. Maybe you can update your question with the code for the SelectionChangeHandler and how you add the selectionModel to the CellList.

Comment: Ok i have added the code. Please let me know what else is required. @timeu i have updated the add, edit, delete calls also.

Comment: Ok thanks I haven't tried the code myself but I checked the issue tracker of GWT and it seems there is a bug entry for that error. See here: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5227&q=CellList%20selectionModel&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Milestone%20Summary%20Stars.

It seems a workaround is to call ListDataProvider.refresh() befor you call setSelected()

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem with GWT 2.5.1.
Deselecting the object programmatically was not working: the next row was selected when I deleted the object from the list of the data provider (and the deselection threw another unwanted event).
The solution was to do:

```
selectionModel.getSelectedSet().clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue: @vbjain wrote: Now when I update or delete element using `cellList.getList().set(index, bean)` or `cellList.getList().remove()` it sucessfully do the operation. But after that it automatically selects the first record in `CellList` which I do not want.

After hours of googling I found, that it happend when keyboard policy is:

```
KeyboardSelectionPolicy.BOUND_TO_SELECTION
```

If you select `KeyboardSelectionPolicy.DISABLED`, you can not list up/down by keyboard, but the issue with selection of first row is resolved.